# How to check placeholder content in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing

I have the below html code:

```
 <input formControlName="firstName"  type="text" class="form-control"
      placeholder="Please enter the First Name">
  </div>
```

I want to do a component test where I check if the placeholder contains: "Please enter First Name".

The below code only returns the value. Is there a way to get the placeholder content?

```
 expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input[formcontrolname="firstName"]').value)
.toContain("John");
```

Comment: Use `.placeholder` (might need a cast to `HTMLInputElement` if you want typing).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getAttribute()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

```
expect(element.getAttribute("placeholder")).toEqual("Please enter the First Name")
```